# Image to Text - Pytesseract struggles with digits on windows

Tags: python, image-processing, reinforcement-learning, python-tesseract

I'm trying to preprocess frames of a game in real-time for a ML project.
I want to extract numbers from the frame, so I chose Pytesseract, since it looked quite good with text.
Though, no matter how clear I make the text, it won't read it correctly.
My code looks like this:

```py
section = process_screen(screen_image)[1]
pixels = rgb_to_bw(section) #Makes the image grayscale
pixels[pixels < 200] = 0 #Makes all non-white pixels black
tess.image_to_string(pixels)

=> 'ye ml)'
```

At best it outputs "ye ml)" when I don't specify I want digits, and when I do, it outputs nothing at all.

The non-processed game image looks like so:
[image: Unprocessed Image]

The "pixels" image looks like so :
[image: Pixels image]

Thanks to Alex Alex, I inverted the image, and got this [image: Alex Alex Better]

And got "2710", which is better, but still not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You must invert the image before recognition.

Comment: That almost worked. It now finds "2710". Why doesn't it work with white text, is there something with the algorithm ?