# Pytesseract cant read numbers on screenshot

Tags: python, image, ocr, python-tesseract

Hello can figure out why pytesseract cant read this numbers, my result: cre

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCGdI.png)

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Users\\X\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(265, 110, 50, 20))
im.save("screenshot.png")
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("screenshot.png")))
```

Anyone know how i can improve the outcome?

Comment: Image quality is not good that is the reason you are not able to see expected results. You can try to pre-process image first.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62136529/13226440

Answer (score 1):

You should preprocess the image before running Tesseract (python code with opencv library):

```
    import cv2

    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\Users\\X\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"
    im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(265, 110, 50, 20))
    im= cv2.bitwise_not(im)
    im.save("screenshot.png")
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("screenshot.png")))
```

[image]